# MacPorts setting an install as Active?

Tags: macports

I currently have the following MacPorts installed:

```
 ImageMagick @6.6.4-9_0+q16
 ImageMagick @6.6.5-0_0+q16 (active)
```

How do I set 6.6.4 as active?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `activate` and `deactivate` commands. for example:

`port deactivate ImageMagick@6.6.5-0_0+q16`

`port activate  ImageMagick@6.6.4-9_0+q16`

Note i may be wrong about the `@` syntax for the version... you may want to confirm that in the documentation.

Comment: `port select python` tells me "none" is active, but when i try to tell it to activate `python27` it says I have to specify the full version as recorded in the port registry, listing all `python27` versions and showing the latest as already active.  so how can i activate it in the first listing?

Comment: @Michael By full version it means the the Full spec like `python27@2.7.6` or `python27@2.7.6+ucs4`  (if you used the ucs4 variant). But are you sure you have python27 installed?